VB.NET Detect external process is open, is so then close
I have an application that calls an external executable with the code below.
Try
    'Call Process 
    Dim ProcessPath As String = "C:\Temp\"
    Dim commandStr As String = "arg1 arg2"
    startInfo.FileName = ProcessPath & "application.exe"
    startInfo.Arguments = commandStr
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    ApplicationProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)
Catch ex As Exception
    ApplicationProcess.Kill()
End Try

The application converts a document to an RTF document, but sometimes there are bad documents. The application is actually a windowed application, but using arguments, I can suppress the window from showing up. However, if the document is not in the right format, then the application shows a windowed alert (see below). In the Task Manager, there are a whole bunch of instances taking up memory.

How does .NET handle the Process.Start() function? When the Process.Start() line gets executed, does the main application pause and continue after the external application has completed? Or does the called external application open in another thread and the main application continues?
How can I detect if an alert has opened and then close it?

How long does the conversion take? Can you put it behind a Timer and just kill it regardless?

The conversion it self doesn't take long, but there are usually millions of files to convert at a given time. If the application converts just fine, the application automatically just closes.

The external application opens in another process, not just another thread (that's kind of the whole point), but it's close to your second proposal.  If you want to detect if a particular dialog has opened, it may be that you can find the window and send a message to it.

Note that Process implements IDisposable, so you should always either have an instance in a Using block or explicitly Dispose it.

It seems that the application isn't designed for server usage. This also means that if the application isn't free, you may be violating the license agreement. Is this why you blurred some of the text on the Windows?

Use spy++ to find the windowclass of the error dialog.
In the FindWindow call replace "#32770" with it's classname and "error" with it's caption if applicable.
The FindWindowEx calls are optional but serve the purpose of making sure we have the right dialog box.
Private Sub CloseErrorDialog()
     Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
     Try
         Dim errorHwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "error")
         If errorHwnd Then
             If FindWindowEx(errorHwnd, Nothing, "Static", "Error while reading file") <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                 ' you either find the button and send it a click
                 Dim butHandle = FindWindowEx(errorHwnd, Nothing, "Button", "OK")
                 SendMessage(butHandle, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
                 Debug.Print("Error dialog closed")
                 ' or you send a process kill
             End If
         End If
     Catch
         Debug.Print("CloseErrorDialog Exception")
     End Try
End Sub
 
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)>
Public Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr : End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Public Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr,
                  ByVal childAfter As IntPtr,
                  ByVal lclassName As String,
                  ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
End Function

you can now periodically call CloseErrorDialog() in a timer or the likes

Have you tested this code? See  FindWindow & FindWindowEx broken on Windows 11

Oh i didn't know Win11 was so broken, i knew it was bad but still.

that post is old tho. is it still broken? i don't have windows 11 to test.
